How do I increase pressure so I can run two showers heads at same time
I am about to remodel my master bath and create a rather large shower.  I want to upgrade it to two shower heads.  They will both be running at same time.  Right now the water pressure is ok but I don't think in its current form it will handle two at the same time. I probably wont be running low flow shower heads either because they don't seem to have the pressure and span I like. I'm game if anyone know of good shower heads that are low flow.
Here is what I have for a plumbing system.  I am on a well that the pump switches are set at 40/60 with a 82 gallon Flotec pressure tank(I think it is actually only 36 gal of water and the rest air).  I have 38 PSI in the tank.  I have a 122 gal tank that I mix chlorine in to rid the water of sulfur, then it goes to a whole house Colligan filter (5 ft tank), then to a Colligan water softener, 4 ft tank. That is the order of the water flow.  It goes to the house via 3/4 PVC pipe.  I have no idea what size I have at the shower, yet!
What do you guys recommend to get pressure and flow for two shower heads.  Just to throw a wrench in,  I also want to do a body sprayer on one wall.  But it wont be running with both showers , it will be by itself but tied into the same water circuit.  The house was built in 93, if that helps.

To test it, turn on shower you have now, turn on a sink faucet, if pressure is still good, flush the toilet.

Did that just now, no discernable pressure drop, with all three going.  They were all in same bathroom though.

Unless you have many more sinks/toilets and nasty people who like to play planks, then you should be okay.  Pressure drop happens when water is flowing out of different openings/faucets.  With three open at the same time and very limited pressure drop, you should be good to go.  Would worry more about the hot water tank having enough hot water to do two shower heads to last.

you say "pressure" but you seem to mean "flow"

Maybe... I believe having two showers may affect both.  So if I can do something while I am remodeling that would be the perfect time.  I'm on a slab so only the plumbing coming out the floor will be exposed.

I talked to a friend of mine who remodels houses for a living.  He said a sure way is to run a 3/4 line from the water heater to the shower diverter valve.  For me that is a long run, almost the entire house length, plus it would be in the attic.  Can anyone think of any other solutions?
